# How to get number of row?

Tags: ios, objective-c, uitableview

i have array with names, these array i pushed to tableView. Now i'm getting string from row, but need to get row int number.

*how i get string name*

```
if(searching)
    {
        [delegate nameObject:[search objectAtIndex:row.row]];
    }
    else
    {
    [delegate nameObject:[[[Data sharedData] ObjectsArray] objectAtIndex:row.row]];
    }
```

*and*

```
-(void)nameObject:(NSString*)name
{
    if(name != Nil && ![name isEqual:@""])
    {   
    // some code
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you need number of row which you selected, implement `UITableViewDelegate` method:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {
    // This is you row int number
    NSInteger myIndex = indexPath.row;

    // This is how you get your name from dataSource  
    NSString * myName = [[[Data sharedData] ObjectsArray] objectAtIndex:myIndex];
}
```

Comment: Объявил интеджер, вместо "row.row" вставил у себя "myIndex", передает имя первого элемента массива, хоть бы число уже, так нет, имя...

Comment: Ну так, интежер это и есть твое число. Если оно тебе надо в виде строки, выведи его так:  
    `NSString * myIndexStr = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", myIndex];
    NSLog(@"Тап по ячейке: %@", myIndexStr);`